# Phaser 2 bug in running the program

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm using vs code as editor and typescript as language for my code
I'm trying to create a web game using phaser2
and this problem occur : "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Phaser'."
I already installed phaser folders in my project and when I try to write import it says another error..

please help is anyone faced this problem?

[image]

Comment: If my anser doesn't help, I recommend setting up your project new based on the official [phaser typescript template](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-typescript-project-template),  and just copy relevant section of your code, into the new project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you seem to be mixing **phaser-ce (*aka phaser 2)*** and **phaser 3**, concepts in your question.

- if you are using **phaser 2** there is no `Scene` *class*, so your code would not work and/or the typedefinitions will not match (or through alot of errors).

About the Error you are encountering, just comment in the ***line 4*** and the compiler should not through an error, *if the phaser version you are loading is phaser 3.*

if you ***don't want use the import phaser statement*** you can add `types` in your  **tsconfig.json *(or jsconfig.json)***.
Just add `'phaser'` to `types` array, or add the property `types`, if it doesn't exist, your config could look like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        //... other configurations
        "types": ["phaser",] // <- added phaser type
     },
     //... other configurations 
}
```

This should be enough for the vs-code "compiler".

**Update / Extra:**
If you are using phaser-ce (aka phaser 2) and nodejs, I would recommend setting up your system as documented here([npm phaser-ce page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phaser-ce)).
*(phaser-ce is not really recommended for new developments)*

If you are using phaser 3  and nodejs, I would recommend setting up your system as documented here ([npm phaser page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phaser)).

**Final Update:**
If the aformentioned points, don't help, I recommend setting up your project from scratch, based on the official [phaser typescript template](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-typescript-project-template), and just copy relevant section of your code, into the new project structure.
*Or you can use [this alternative official template](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser3-project-template), it is slightly more complex, but I think this type of project is used more often.*

Comment: i tried to add that templates and still cant fix that issue is there a way i can send you my files and you take a look ?

Comment: @YarinGx If your project is on github or so, you could post that link here, and I can have a quick look.

Comment: Yes i would,
https://github.com/YarinGx/HomeAssignment
i have to finish it until monday :<

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at this code (https://github.com/YarinGx/HomeAssignment), due to the fact, that there is a `.scene` file, I assume this is a project that is, created with https://phasereditor2d.com/, so I would recommend to use that editor to alter this project.
Opening the project with this editor, works (if you remove `import Phaser from "phaser";`)

In VSCode, if you remove `import Phaser from "phaser";` on line 4, of the file `MainScene.ts` compiling should work. I just added the file

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

and just compile with: `tsc -p .`

**btw.:** I would also remove this line

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
```

from the `index.html`, I don't think it makes sense to have it there.

Comment: @YarinGx sure thing,  not problem. It would be nice, if you could consider up voting or giving the answer the green check mark.